# How to use GROUP BY to concat strings in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, concatenation

normal query

```
id  sid  string
5    1    AAA
6    1    BBB
7    2    CCC
8    3    ZZZ
9    3    EEE
```

i want

```
sid  string
1    1. AAA 2. BBB
2    1. CCC
3    1. ZZZ 2. EEE
```

Do you have any idea how to do?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: In `sid=3`, why are `ZZZ` and `EEE` #1 and #2 respectively, and not the other way around?  Or does it not matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function get the values into a single row and you can use user-defined variables to assign the number to each value in the `sid` group:

```
select sid,
  group_concat(concat(rn, '. ', string) ORDER BY id SEPARATOR ' ') string
from
(
  select id,
    sid,
    string,
    @row:=case when @prev=sid then @row else 0 end +1 rn,
    @prev:=sid
  from yourtable
  cross join (select @row:= 0, @prev:=null) r
  order by id
) src
group by sid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20448/6), The result is:

```
| SID |        STRING |
-----------------------
|   1 | 1. AAA 2. BBB |
|   2 |        1. CCC |
|   3 | 1. ZZZ 2. EEE |
```

Comment: This is mind-boggling. I've used group_concat before but never thought about numbering the strings themselves while concatenating them.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the **[GROUP_CONCAT() function of MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).**

But the numbering I would do in PHP.