# groupBy in laravel function similarly to distinct?

Tags: laravel-5

My records in 'answers table':

```
**id    question_id   answer**

  20      12          app/Http/routes.ph
  21      13          uri
  22      13          closure
  23      14          controller
  24      15          class name
  25      15          App\Http\Controllers
  26      16          for displayh
```

My code to retrieve data:

```
$qas= DB::table('answers')
         ->groupBy('question_id')
         ->get();
        dump($qas);
    }
```

I get only 5 records instead of 7; where the other 2 records?
It works similarly to distinct function which is not my intention.

How to write code to get all 7 record which are grouped by 'question_id'?

Comment: if my answer was helpful, please choose my answer as best answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Understand the concept of `GroupBy`, its mean that, it will consider same items as one, eg `14, 14-> 14 | 13,13-> 13` if you want to get all answer, then you have to write this

```
DB::table('answers')->get();
```

**Edited**

distinct and group by will do same action in your case. 
If You can explain your problem in more details, then may be there is possible solution are.

Comment: My table "answer table' has field: id, question_id, and answer. I want to get all records for answer column, but the records must be categoried or group by question column.

Comment: `DB::table('answers')->select('question_id', DB::raw(group_concat(answer SEPARATOR ',') AS ans) )->groupBy('question_id')->get();`

for reference have a look [Link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql?answertab=votes#tab-top) [Link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273118/how-to-use-group-by-to-concat-strings-in-mysql?answertab=votes#tab-top)
[Link 3](http://www.giombetti.com/2013/06/06/mysql-group_concat/)

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about result with 7 rows, but that's not grouping. Maybe you're talking about ordering instead of grouping? If so, you'd want to use `->orderBy('question_id', 'asc')`, that will give you 7 rows, sorted by `question_id`.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, GROUP BY clause is useful when you need to aggregate the result in a sort of way for example for SUM or AVERAGE of data.

Your case is different, you don't need to aggregate data using some function, you simply need a different data structure other than a simply and flat result list.

For your need, you should avoid GROUP BY, and reorder data in your code in a programmatic way.